# What's the point of updating Joomla?

Tags: security, web, joomla, frontend

I'm currently running and installation of Joomla v3.3.3 on a server. It says that there's an update available for v3.5.1. I'd like to know if it's a good idea to update to this version. There are several additional modules used by the website and I'm afraid that the whole frontend will be broken after updating. Are there any security issues? Or am I fine if I'm staying on this version?

Comment: Yes, you're current version has a security vulnerability. Joomla 3.4.8 fixes these. Update sin general should always been installed for security purposes, bug fixes, and newest features.......always!

Comment: But isn't it possible that a bunch of modules/themes/whatever stop working then?

Comment: The uodate you're refrring to is not a major update so all extension should still work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its always best to stay up to date as the updates frequently address various security concerns. Its not difficult for a potential attacker to know when a website is built on the various popular frameworks. I can spot a joomla or wordpress site every time.

It is also best practice to backup your website before performing updates.
Myself, I like to create a copy of the entire site and database in another directory or sub domain and test update on that. if all seems good i then create a backup of the live site before installing the update as updates can fail for random reasons.

[joomla updating guide](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Updating_from_an_existing_version)

Answer (score 0):

It's a best practice in web development to stay up to date, with updates we have improvements in security, functionality, performance or design.

Some extensions are not compatible with the latest joomla! versions, so you also need check the news for each extension in their websites, also you can check the updates in:

- **Extensions** > **Manage** > **Update** > **Find Updates** Button

If for some reason you have an extension that should not be updated and you see the notification in the back-end, you can disable it in:

- **Extensions** > **Manage** > **Update** > **Update Sites**

---

Note: Before any change in your site, create a backup. One popular extension to automate your backup process is [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-security/akeeba-backup).